# How to insert table in Word after another one with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to insert a table after another one with VBA in Word. I have a button, clicking on which should cause insertion of some new table (with borders, filled with words) five table rows under the button. I've tried some examples, like

```
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=5
With ThisDocument
Set table1 = .Tables.Add(.Range(Start:=myInt, End:=myInt), 2, 7)
End With
table1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range = "text"
table1.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
table1.Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
```

It makes table with borders, but it is being inserted at the beginning of the document and I need it five rows below the selected cell. I can't get how to specify myInt to place the table 5 rows below.

Maybe there is another way to do this.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Set table1 = .Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 2, 7)
```

But you would be much better served by avoiding the use of Selection if you can.